# cannot remove directory rm: cannot remove ‘/opt/odoo/.gvfs’: Device or resource busy

Tags: user-management, odoo

I've created a system user using this command

```
sudo adduser --system --home=/opt/odoo --group odoo
```

and when I tried to remove it later using this command 
`userdel -r odoo` I got this error

```
userdel: error removing directory /opt/odoo
```

when I tried to remove it manually `sudo rm -rvf /opt/odoo` I got this

```
rm: cannot remove ‘/opt/odoo/.gvfs’: Device or resource busy
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below command then try to remove user:

```
sudo umount /run/user/root/gvfs
```

Comment: Here's what I get: umount: /run/user/root/gvfs: mountpoint not found

Comment: The mountpoint is more likely to be `/run/user/$(id -u odoo)/gvfs` on current systems, I think